# Get html form values and convert to Json array Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I have a form like this in my view:

```html
<form action="http://localhost/RenderForm/public/handle-form" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="BOwsdSS3Zc4oI08wDutUQbvtQhGvGZXBgxaOoOFD">                                                                    
    <div class="links">
        <div>
         First Name:<br>
         <input name="firstName" type="text">
        </div>        
        <br>
    </div>
                                                
    <div class="links">
        <div>
         Last Name:<br>
         <input name="lastName" type="text">
        </div>        
        <br>
    </div>
                                                
    <div class="links">
        <div>
         Location:<br>
         <select name="location">
    <option value="0">HN</option>
    <option value="1">HCM</option>
   </select>
        </div>        
        <br>
    </div>
                                            
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Reset Form</button>
        <button type="submit">Complete Task</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my controller, I use $request->all() to get all form values and store into a variable. After that, I use json_encode to convert it become a Json object.
When I debug that variable, it have values:

> "{"firstName":"hao","lastName":"nguyen","location":"0"}"

But what I really need is:

> [
>       {
>         "id" : "firstName",
>         "value" : "hao"
>       },
>       {
>         "id" : "lastName",
>         "value" : "nguyen"
>       },
>       {
>         "id" : "location",
>         "value" : "0"
>       }   ]

Can you tell me how to fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try  ```$arr = [json_decode(json_encode($request->all()), true)];```

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "_token" => "RKvYNS7ubX4x2AGGxSU7Rwp6ClYJnnq4TSr1ob8c"
    "firstName" => "hao"
    "lastName" => "nguyen"
    "location" => "0"
  ]
]

Comment: it's not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach loop and customised all inputs like this :

```
$collect = []; // empty array for collect customised inputs

foreach($request->all() as $input_key => $input_value){ // split input one by one

     $collect[] = array( //customised inputs
            "id" => $input_key,
            "value" => $input_value

     );
} 

$result = json_encode($collect); //convert to json
```

Comment: exactly what I need. Thank you very much! You saved my day :))